# Looking for file format of blackboard quiz files

Tags: xml, format, blackboard

I am looking to import a quiz in Schoology. They support blackboard quiz format, but I don't have blackboard. I was redirected to https://quondam.csi.edu/blackboard/bbquiz/ in order to generate the quiz file, but this tool results in a corrupted zip file.

It seems to generate a file called imsmanifest.xml but I can't see its contents.

I'd like to know if there are other tools out there that can generate those quiz zip files, or where to get a spec/example for the format so I can figure out how to generate it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer this myself. I found out the online tool actually does work, but I used 7-zip to unzip it. Somehow this program has a bug. When I use the native Windows 'extract all...' I can view the contents and I now see how the blackboard quiz is formatted.

First there is an imsmanifest.xml like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest identifier="man00001">
<organization default="toc00001">
<tableofcontents identifier="toc00001"/>
</organization>
<resources>
<resource baseurl="res00001" file="res00001.dat" identifier="res00001" type="assessment/x-bb-pool"/>
</resources>
</manifest>
```

Then there is the dat file as referenced in the manifest, that looks e.g. like this:
https://pastebin.com/hwPUPHEN